# Express an abelian group given as finite generators and their relations as a direct sum of cyclic groups and find corresponding generators.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

According to page 158 of Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* (3rd edition):

> **Theorem.** (*Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups*) Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group. Then
>
> **(1)** $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^r \times Z_{n_1} \times Z_{n_2} \times ... \times Z_{n_s}$, for some integers $r$, $n_1$, $n_2$, ... , $n_s$ satisfying the following conditions: **(a)** $r \ge 0$ and $n_j \ge 2$ for all $j$, and **(b)** $n_{i+1} \mid n_i$ for $1 \le i \le s-1$
>
> **(2)** the expression in (1) is unique: if $G\cong \mathbb{Z}^t \times Z_{m_1} \times Z_{m_2} \times ... \times Z_{m_u}$, where $t$ and $m_1$, $m_2$, ... , $m_u$ satisfy (a) and (b) (i.e., $t \ge 0$, $m_j \ge 2$ for all $j$ and $m_{i+1} \mid m_i$ for $1 \le i \le u-1$), then $t = r$, $u = s$ and $m_i = n_i$ for all $i$.

**Question:** If an abelian group is expressed as finite generators and their defining relations (for example $G = \langle s,t,u,v \mid s^{4}t^{2}u^{10}v^{6} = s^{8}t^{4}u^{8}v^{10} = s^{6}t^{2}u^{9}v^{8} = e_G\rangle$), how to compute and express the group as a direct sum of cyclic groups and **find the corresponding generators satisfying the relations**? Could someone explain the computing procedure and show some worked examples? Or could someone point out which textbook taught such computing procedure with worked examples and at which pages/sections?

**P.S.1** Although I can't find which textbook taught such computing procedure, Derek Holt gave a link to a PDF document teaching such computing procedure in his comment.

**P.S.2.** Could someone reply my 2nd comment of lhf's answer and explain **how to find that 4 generators in $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty}$ satisfying the relations?**

Comment: After a bit of searching, I found [this link](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/groups/CHAP10%20Finitely-Generated%20Abelian%20Groups.pdf), which seems to explain everything with worked examples.

Comment: If |a| = $\infty$ then <a> ~ Z, if |a| = m then <a> ~ $Z_m$.  So that fundamental expression is the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

The tool for this is the [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), a kind of Gaussian elimination for PID.

For the example $G = \langle s,t,u,v \mid s^{4}t^{2}u^{10}v^{6} = s^{8}t^{4}u^{8}v^{10} = s^{6}t^{2}u^{9}v^{8} = e_G \rangle$ written additively, the matrix is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & 2 & 10 & 6 \\
 8 & 4 & 8 & 10 \\
 6 & 2 & 9 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
whose Smith Normal Form is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
as computed by Mathematica using the code mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40924/19574).

This means that $G$ is generated by four elements $g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$ such that $1g_1=0$, $2g_2=0$, $2g_3=0$, and no restrictions on $g_4$, and so $G \cong C_1 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty} \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty}$.

$g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$ are obtained from $s,t,u,v$ by applying the matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PAQ$ is the diagonal matrix above.

All this is explained in several books. One is 
*Finitely Generated Abelian Groups and Similarity of Matrices over a Field* by Christopher Norman. A shorter account appears in Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*.

Comment: Thank you!! (1) Could you please explain a little more (or give a sketch of proof) why this computing will yield the result corresponding to the correct direct sum of cyclic groups? (Or which book contains the proof and at which pages/sections?) (2) How to tell/compute which elements in $C_{\infty} \times C_2 \times C_2$ correspond to the generators $s,t,u,v$?

Comment: By (2) I mean since $G \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty}$ and $G$ is generated by 4 elements satisfying those 3 relations, there must also be 4 elements in $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty}$ generating $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty}$ and satisfying those 3 relations. Is there a method to find such 4 elements in $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty}$? Thanks!

Comment: When will you reply my 2nd comment and explain how to find that 4 generators in $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_{\infty}$ satisfying the relations?

Comment: @Tien-ChengHuang, using the $P$ and $Q$ matrices I've mentioned. You have to perform the algorithm for computing the Smith Normal Form to find these matrices.

Answer (score -1):

If G has generators {$a_1.... a_r$} where $|a_i|= \infty$ and {$b_1...b_t$} where $|b_i| = m_i$ then G = $\prod_{i=1}^r<a_i> \times \prod_{j=1}^t<b_j>$.  But each $\langle a_i \rangle \cong \mathbb Z$ so $\prod_{i=1}^r \cong \mathbb Z^r$ and each $\langle b_j \rangle \cong \mathbb Z_{m_j}$ so $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^r \times Z_{m_1} \times Z_{m_2} \times ... \times Z_{m_t}$

Comment: In general, the relations you're given are not necessarily of the form $b_i^{m_i} = 1$. There is some linear algebra involved in finding nice generators. For example, if you are given generators $a$ and $b$ with relation $a^4 = b^2$ (and of course $ab = ba$), then how are you supposed to guess that you should really take $a$ and $a^{-2}b$ as your generators (of infinite order and order $2$, respectively)?